# Misconfiguration error when accessing URL without file name

Tags: url, error, htaccess

When accessing www.myurl.com/`services`, I get this error **below** the content of my page:

`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

I don't get this error if I access www.myurl.com/`index.php/services`. I'm new to Craft, but am particularly confused, because nothing else on my site is broken, I just keep getting this error appended to the end of my html. Additionally, I have followed the directions to include an `.htaccess` file in the web root. This error does not occur locally. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you see any indication of where the error occurs in the error log of your web server?

Comment: Did you not change the htacces to .htaccess? (happens to me occasionaly)?

Answer (score 1):

On some servers you might need to add in general.php

```
'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true
```

See https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings

Hope that helps